# How to achieve fast focusing at lower frame rate in android camera or how to choose best frame rate

Tags: android, google-api, computer-vision, android-camera, android-camera2

I am using Google mobile vision for Qr code detection and OCR which is supported by Camera APi(not camera2 api).

I fixed frame rates to 15fps, but in some devices preview is very slow and takes too long say 5-6 seconds to focus but good low light visibility. If I change frame rate to 30fps preview is very smooth and focus is fast but low light visibility is very poor and preview in some phones is giving a glitch/flickering frames.

What can I do to achieve good focus,smooth preview and manageable low light visibility? Should I go with Camera2 APi to achieve this? Or any others suggestions or advice to achieve this will be more helpful.

Creating camera source with ocr detection

```
  mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(height, width)
                .setRequestedFps(30.0f) // 15 or 30FPS?
                .setFocusMode(autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE : null)
                .setFlashMode(useFlash ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH : null)
                .build();
```

Qr code detection, frames are separately fed to Qr code detector.

```
 Frame frame = new Frame.Builder()
        .setImageData(byteBufferData, size.width,size.height, camFormat)
        .build();
    SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(frame);
```

I tried changing frame rate to different value(within available range) but that didn't help.